USB wifi adapter gets disconnect every 5-10 minutes on my desktop station
I have a USB WiFi card on my desktop PC, specifically an "Edimax AC600 EW-7811UTC". It frequently disconnects from the WiFi (but does not turn off). Here is what I have tried so far:
Reinstalled the driver and set up the device again.
Reset my network settings in Windows.
Used Windows' Network troubleshooter, which couldn't help.
Ran the following commands in CMD as an administrator:
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns
Changing my DNS address
Downloaded the latest version of the driver from the internet and manually configured it.
Despite all these steps, I am still frequently encountering the "No Internet, secured" error on my WiFi.
I have noticed that this problem is quite common and have not found a straightforward solution.
Can anyone provide any advice or potential solutions to fix this issue?

I have edited the question according to your feedback.

What does Event Viewer say is happening when (or around the time) the disconnects occur? Are there any other devices connected to this wireless network? If so, do any of them have any odd behaviors around the time the connection disconnects?

@music2myear From Event Viewer which feature do I have to check? There are other devices connected to this wireless network and all of them are working very well. As I mentioned before and deleted the answer after changing through 3.0 USB port everything looks fine. However I am engaged and want to help others to solve this problem permanently.

Your answer needed to be fixed, not deleted. Please read the HELP section to understand how this site works.
